# How should I route the ground plane under a RF trace with a LC balun?

Tags: rf, filter, layout, wifi, impedance-matching

I'm designing a PCB with a ESP32-PICO-V3, with a RF output to a 50 Ohms U.FL (Micro-Coax) connector. The chip supports WiFi and Bluetooth in the frequency range 2.45 +/- 0.45 GHz.

Right now, I have a prototype with a 0 Ohms resistor in lieu of the CLC filter suggested in the [Hardware Design Guidelines](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp32_hardware_design_guidelines_en.pdf) (pdf), which also states that the output impedance of the chip is ~(30 + 10j) Ohms (for the 6x6mm package, I have the 7x7), and I get 45 Mbps with iPerf test.

However, I'd like to improve the circuit with a true LC Balun filter. According to [this site](https://analog.intgckts.com/impedance-matching/lumped-lc-balun/) (and a few others), I get the following design::[image].

I'm wondering: how do I route the plane under the RF trace with this type of connection to ground? I currently have the following layout:[image].

My guess is that it will work however I do it, since it already works with no filter or matching. But I want to minimize EMI right from the start. Otherwise, should I just follow the guideline of putting a CLC filter and be done with it?

Other info: the stackup is Er = 4.05 and height = 3.5 mils. Traces are 6 mils wide.

Comment: The u.fl coax connector is for an unbalanced line, and the chip has an unbalanced antenna pin. Why do you want a balun? You just need a conventional impedance matching network.

Comment: Ah! It seems I had the concepts of impedance matching and line balancing mixed up. If I got this correctly, a balun can also include impedance matching, but need not do so. Since my input and output are both unbalanced, I only need the impedance matching part. So the CLC Pi matching circuit is the way to go. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As [Mark Leavitt](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/261130/mark-leavitt) commented, both the chip and connectors are unbalanced lines, so a balun (**bal**anced-to-**un**balanced) is not what I need here, although it can also include an impedance matching function. I only need the functionality of a CLC Pi matching circuit... just as the Hardware Design Guide suggests!

It seems [EEWeb provides a nice calculator](https://www.eeweb.com/tools/pi-match/) for this case, which is faster than re-learning the contents of [Microwave and RF Wireless Systems by David M. Pozar](https://books.google.ca/books/about/Microwave_and_RF_Design_of_Wireless_Syst.html?id=QDX-DwAAQBAJ&redir_esc=y)